# How to add EditText value in arraylist in Custom ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I have created two TextView and one EditText in my first custom ListView,I want to add/store EditText value in Arraylist because i want to show EditText value in second Custom ListView one by one,so how to do this please give the hint or code to solve this problem..

```
public class Mmenu extends Activity {
ArrayList<Candy> myArrList;
ArrayList<String> editTextValues;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myArrList = new ArrayList<Candy>();
    editTextValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ListView lisView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    final ListView lisView2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);

    myArrList.add(new Candy("Butterscotch", "Rs 10"));
    myArrList.add(new Candy("Birthday Cake", "Rs 100"));
    myArrList.add(new Candy("Black Crunch", "Rs 102"));
    myArrList.add(new Candy("Industrial Chocolate", "Rs 200"));
    myArrList.add(new Candy("Coffee Molasses Chip", "Rs 500"));      


    lisView1.setAdapter(new CountryAdapter(this));


    Button btnGetItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetItem);
    btnGetItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {                
            int count = lisView1.getAdapter().getCount();


            for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
            {
            LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout)lisView1.getChildAt(i);

            EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtInput);
            String value = text.getText().toString();
            editTextValues.add(value);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"10"+value,   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


            lisView2.setAdapter(new CountryAdapter2(getApplicationContext()));
            }
            });
             }


    public class CountryAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
    private Context context;

    public CountryAdapter(Context c)
    {
    //super( c, R.layout.activity_column, R.id.rowTextView, );
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    context = c;
    }
    public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return myArrList.size();
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
    }
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.views, null);
     }
    // ColID
    TextView txtID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nm);
    txtID.setText(myArrList.get(position).getID() +".");
    // ColCode
    TextView txtCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rat);
    txtCode.setText(myArrList.get(position).getCode());
    return convertView;

    }
     }
    public class CountryAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter
    {
    private Context context;
    public CountryAdapter2(Context c)
    {
        context = c;
    }
    public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return myArrList.size();
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
    }
     public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
    }
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null)
    {convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newviews, null);
    }

    // ColID
    TextView txtID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nm);
    txtID.setText(myArrList.get(position).getID() +".");
    // ColCode
    TextView txtCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rat);
    txtCode.setText(myArrList.get(position).getCode());
    return convertView;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are wasting a lot of space by creating a new `HashMap<String, String>` every time. Not sure why you would have an `ArrayList` of `HashMaps`. Having one or the other should be sufficient.

You can create a class called Candy like such:

```
class Candy {
    private String id;
    private String code;
    Candy(String id, String code) {
        this.id = id;
        this.code = code;
    }
    public String getID() { return this.id; }
    public String getCode() { return this.code; }
}
```

Then you can define your `ArrayList` and instantiate it in the beginning of `onCreate()`:

```
// Don't use starting capital letters for methods, classes have first capital letter
// I renamed MyArrList to myArrList
ArrayList<Candy> myArrList;
// ...
void onCreate() {
// ...
    myArrList = new ArrayList<Candy>();
// ...
}
```

And populate it like:

```
myArrList.add(new Candy("Butterscotch", "Rs 10"));
myArrList.add(new Candy("Birthday Cake", "Rs 100"));
myArrList.add(new Candy("Black Crunch", "Rs 102"));
myArrList.add(new Candy("Industrial Chocolate", "Rs 200"));
myArrList.add(new Candy("Coffee Molasses Chip", "Rs 500"));
```

Now you can use the getter methods of the `Candy` class called `getID()` and `getCode()`.

Change:

```
// ColID
TextView txtID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nm);
txtID.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("ID") +".");
    // ColCode
TextView txtCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rat);
txtCode.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("Code"));
```

To:

```
// ColID
TextView txtID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nm);
txtID.setText(myArrList.get(position).getID() +".");
// ColCode
TextView txtCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rat);
txtCode.setText(myArrList.get(position).getCode());
```

Now to answer your question, I assume you want to store the text that is within the `EditText` field into an `ArrayList`.

You can create another class `ArrayList` object that holds `String` objects and instantiate it in `onCreate()`.

```
ArrayList<String> editTextValues;
// ...
void onCreate() {
// ...
    editTextValues = new ArrayList<String>();
// ...
}
```

Now you can just add text from `EditText` to this `ArrayList`:

```
EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_ID);
String value = text.getText().toString();
editTextValues.add(value);
```

And then use the `editTextValues` where you need them.

Comment: then what to do for EditText

Comment: I need one more help when i click on getInputItem i want to show all records of first ListView to Second ListView, in my code it show only two textView record i want to editText value also

Comment: I cannot help you without other information. You need to specifically describe what goes wrong, are any errors shown, if they are what do the errors say and what piece of code causes the errors

Comment: I update my code check it, i need to set all EditText value of first Custom ListView to Second Custom ListView EditText ,In my when i toast on button click it show only first EditText value

Comment: I am sorry but your wording is confusing. I believe you should do for the second `ListView` is: 'EditText text2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtInput2);
            String value = editTextValues.get(0);
            text2.setText(value, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);'

Comment: where i have to put this code EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstEdittext);
String value = text.getText().toString();
editTextValues.add(value);

Comment: in onCreate or in  getView